# How to search for files by file type on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for files in a particular directory that have the following extensions : txt, csv or xml

The directory has many levels of subdirectories that I would like to search for all 3 file types in one go.

So in the explorer I type <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> and type some thing like `*.txt;*.csv;*.xml`. But after a long time of watching a green bar fill up I get zero results.

However there are hundreds of files of thoses types from this directory down.

How can I do such a search in Windows 8?

Comment: Make sure you are search in "files". (Neither **Settings** or **Apps**)

Comment: @techie007 No, it's not the same question, at least it does not help me. I am in a directory in Windows explorer and I do Ctrl+F. I want to search from there. I don't want to have to locate again the very folder I am in.

Comment: Oooh so you want to search for multiple file types/extensions at the same time.  Sorry, I thought your comma separated list was different extensions you tried.

Comment: Searching from GUI takes most of time as it relies on the indexing service, if time is the killer go for console with https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717502/3057246

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On the top right of Windows Explorer, type `*.extension` in the search box.

i.e. to search txt files you should type:

`*.txt`

For multiple files use:

`*.doc OR *.txt OR *.pdf`

[This link can be helpful](https://unitrai.com/operating-systems/windows/how-to-search-files-by-extension-or-multiple-extensions-simultaneously-in-windows-8-or-windows-10/)

[The usage Video Here](https://youtu.be/j7VktBEmqP8)

Comment: This only works for 1 file type, not a combination.

Comment: Ext:.doc OR Ext:.txt OR Ext:.pdf  you can use this for multiple files

Comment: A very useful tip - but note that "OR" must be upper case.

Comment: Another item that I learned recently that could be helpful - you can save searches you run a lot (like, for me, searches by type are common) up on the Search ribbon in Win 8, there's a button for saving it. Can do this from Vista on up, but the mechanism changes

Comment: This particular method is *not* ideal as it lacks precision. If you want to search for `*.doc` files, for example, `*.docx` files will be included in the results.

Answer (score 3):

I find [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) very useful in my daily usage.
The search is highly flexible due to the usage of *wildcards*.
It will scan all your connected hard drives only once and once it has completed scanning all the searches you perform are super duper fast!
To answer your question, your search in Everything would be `*.txt` or `*.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
~>".extension"
```

will bring you all the files on PC which ends exactly with ".extension".
This solves problem of showing unrelated files in search result.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, I don't know why, but I have to type `*extension` **without** a `.` between the `*` and the extension.

For example: not `*.zip`, but `*zip`.